# Play video one after another simultaneously smoothly [without visible switching from one to another]

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview

I am new to android and want to play videos one after another simultaneously so that it looks like continuous video.

I have found this link on stackoverflow very helpful. [how-to-play-videos-one-after-another-simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560445/how-to-play-videos-one-after-another-simultaneously)
When I am using this then though I am able to play videos one after another, 
**But switching from one segment to other results in *pause the video for a second before playing next one*.**  So It don't looks like continuous videos due to this.

Please help me to resolve my problem.
Here is my Code.

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity{

     VideoView videoView, videoView1;
     MediaController mc;
     int count = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VVSimpleVideo);
        setup();
        videoView.setOnCompletionListener(completionListener);

    }

    public void setup() {

        String _path = "/mnt/sdcard/Video/"+count+".mp4";
        videoView.setVideoPath(_path);
        videoView.start();
        count++;
    }


    private OnCompletionListener completionListener=new OnCompletionListener() {

        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.stop();
            setup();
        }
    };

}
```

**Now I have tried to play by taking two instances of VideoView class.**
Tried to play the first video by first player and second video by second player,
Third video from first player and fourth video from second player  and so on.

But still I am not able to play the video smoothly and the same problem exist.

Here is my code with double player.

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity{

     VideoView videoView, videoView1;
     MediaController mc;
     int count = 0;
     String _path;
     String _path1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VVSimpleVideo);
        _path = "/mnt/sdcard/Video/"+count+".mp4";
        videoView.setVideoPath(_path);
         videoView.start();
        //setup();
        videoView.setOnCompletionListener(completionListener);

        videoView1 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VVSimpleVideo);

        videoView1.setOnCompletionListener(completionListener1);
        count++;
        _path1 = "/mnt/sdcard/Video/"+count+".mp4";
        videoView1.setVideoPath(_path1);
    }

    public void setup() {


        videoView.start();
        count++;
        _path1 = "/mnt/sdcard/Video/"+count+".mp4";
        videoView1.setVideoPath(_path1);
    }

    public void setup1() {


        videoView1.start();

        count++;
        _path = "/mnt/sdcard/Video/"+count+".mp4";
        videoView.setVideoPath(_path);
    }

    private OnCompletionListener completionListener=new OnCompletionListener() {

        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.stop();
            setup1();       

        }
    };

    private OnCompletionListener completionListener1=new OnCompletionListener() {

        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.stop();

            setup();        

        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Hi piku, Im also having a similar issue. Were you able to achieve minimal "black screen switch" time?

Comment: use exoPlayer.
this library help you to concatenate multi video together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not really using two `VideoViews` at all, you're assigning both `VideoView` and `VideoView1` to `R.id.VVSimpleVideo`, so they are the same object. That means each time you hit `onCompletion`, it's setting itself up all over again, instead of setting up one and playing the other.

Try creating two separate `VideoView` objects in your layout. Have one set to `VISIBLE` and one set to `GONE`/`INVISIBLE`, and swap when you want to change.

I can't guarantee it will make it "seamless", though, since that's an almost impossible task. Even most desktop media players aren't truly seamless. It just depends on what tolerance you have for seams.

Comment: Hi Geobits,

Thanks for the reply. Thanks for correcting to use two different VideoView in layout.

But it is unable to start the second one if having the GONE/INVISIBLE.
Everytime just first player work when its turn comes.

Then I have tried to set the visibility on the fly by videoView.setVisibility(0);

I don't find  VISIBLE/GONE/INVISIBLE as possible values, so put 0.
Still not able to show frames from second video,  though music is coming.

Comment: Hi 
I am able to change the visibility on the fly by      videoView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)   
But when it is switching it shows some blackout in between, so playing is not smooth.